# Trying to reach localhost from inside Selenium docker

Tags: selenium-webdriver, docker, capybara

I'm trying to run my tests using Selenium docker, 
I have a local grunt server running on port 9000, I' launched the following selenium docker:

```
docker run  -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
```

Then I've launched my tests (using Capybara) and opened VNC to watch the tests, but all I get is chrome messgae "This site can’t be reached".

cabybara.rb:

```
isWindows = (/cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM) != nil

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require_relative 'sinatra_proxy'
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'selenium/webdriver/remote/http/curb' if !isWindows

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
    http_client = isWindows ? nil : Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Curb.new
    options = {
        http_client: http_client,
        browser: :chrome,
        # service_log_path: 'chromedriver.out', # Enable Selenium logs
        switches: ["--disable-web-security", '--user-agent="Chrome under Selenium for Capybara"']
    }
    options[:url] = "http://172.17.0.2:4444/wd/hub"
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, options

end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
Capybara.app = SinatraProxy.new
Capybara.app_host = "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
```

ip addr show docker0

```
ip addr show docker0                                                                  
6: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:22:ec:65:9e:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe40::42:ecdd:fe73:9ef4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Needed to be the IP of docker host, used:

```
ip route show | grep docker0 | awk '{print $9}'
```

for `Capybara.app_host` (DOCKER_HOST_IP:PORT) and `Capybara.server_host` (DOCKER_HOST_IP)

Comment: Have you tried the answers from this question [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: Yes i have, using net=host with selenium image doesn't works, the container closes for some reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
Capybara.app_host = "http://yourhostip:9000"
```

not localhost. For docker container localhost is itself.

Also I recommend not calling docker by its internal ip just use:

```
options[:url] = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
```

But first solve the former problem

Regards

Comment: As app host is simply the url preceding the visit method, I've tried using the host ip directly from the selenium in the VNC, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you access your grunt server from another machine in the network? If so use the same ip you  use to make the connection. If not try to make grunt server be visible from outside

Comment: I dont have another machine, it's just a local server for the app, internet access from inside the container is ok by the way.

Comment: Use your phone, your tablet, anything that try to reach the server from ip. It is to narrow where the problem is

Comment: I will try and keep you posted

Comment: hey, I've updated my answer, from another container (using --net=host) curl worked for localhost.

Comment: Your grunt service is running on your host or in a docker container?

Comment: The grunt service is running on my host, not inside a container.

Comment: Needed to be the IP of docker host, used: ip route show | grep docker0 | awk '{print $9}' for Capybara.app_host (DOCKER_HOST_IP:PORT) and Capybara.server_host (DOCKER_HOST_IP)

Comment: Excellent! . Sorry I couldn't in couple of days follow you. I am very busy these days

Comment: Just FYI, "host.docker.internal" works also. I was wondering if we can somehow map "host.docker.internal" to point to host system localhost ?!?